# exe command not recognised in win32 folder

Tags: vb6, wow64

I have placed a mycmd.exe file in system32 folder under windows directory.
Strange thing is that this is accessible from command prompt but when i access this file as a shell command from my VB6 application it shows is "not recognized as an internal or external command"
I am running VB project as run as administrator and using win8 64bit.

Thanks for the anticipated help!!

Answer (score 2):

The WOW64 filesystem redirector is probably taking your program's path and changing it.

See: [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the exact code you're using to run the EXE? The error you're getting makes it clear that VB isn't finding the file. Have you tried appending the path to the specific file you're trying to execute?